# Could not resolve "pg-native"

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, npm, cloudflare-workers

I'm using Cloudflare Workers to connect a PostgreSQL database hosted in Azure.

The problem is every time, I try to run the code, I get this error:

You can mark the path "pg-native" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error. You can also surround this "require" call with a try/catch block to handle this failure at run-time instead of bundle-time.

X [ERROR] Build failed with 1 error:

node_modules/pg/lib/native/client.js:4:21: ERROR: Could not resolve "pg-native"

I tried npm install pg-native many times, and it results with errors. From other thread I read, that pg-native can't be bundled through esbuild. But in that case what's the solution, or a workaround?

Here's my code:

```
const { Client } = require('pg');

addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})

async function handleRequest(request) {
  const client = new Client({
    user: 'XXX',
    host: 'XXX',
    database: ' XXX  ',
    password: ' XXX  ',
    port: 5432,
  });

  await client.connect();

  const res = await client.query('SELECT * from  XXX ');

  await client.end();

  return new Response(res.rows[0].message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use `esbuild`, then in its config you need to specify external: ['pg-native'].

And if you use something else, then you should also add pg-native to external

```
try {
   const baseOptions = {
     logLevel: 'info',
     bundle: true,
     charset: 'utf8',
     minifyWhitespace: true,
     absWorkingDir: process.cwd(),
     external: ['pg-native'],
   };

   for (const targetOpts of TARGET_ENTRIES) {
     const mergedOpts = { ...baseOptions, ...targetOpts };
     const { errors } = await build(mergedOpts);
     if (errors.length) {
       console.error(`[ESBuild] Bundle failed with ${errors.length} errors`);
       process.exit(1);
     }
   }
 } catch (e) {
   console.log('[ESBuild] Build failed with error');
   console.error(e);
   process.exit(1);
 }
```

Comment: Hi, please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417). Thank you